# Como compartir un articulo de mi web en redes?

Tags: php, html, mysql

lo que sucede es que tengo una pagina donde se cargan unos articulos en una tabla html mediante php y mysql via ajax, el usuario al darle click a ese articulo le abre una pagina donde puede ver información mas detallada, mi pregunta es que debo hacer para que ese articulo se pueda compartir en redes debido a que ese articulo se carga por una consulta mysql por php? he pensado que si es prudente crear un archivo html por cada articulo de la pagina o como se podria hacer dinamicamente que se pueda compartir.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes compartir cualquier articulo que pueda generarse nuevamente desde la url compartida, para que en redes sociales se vea bien ( foto titulo y descripción ) podrías añadir a cada pagina, meta tags para redes.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
<meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/index.htm">
```

Para twitter

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content="European Travel Destinations ">
<meta name="twitter:description" content=" Offering tour packages for individuals or groups.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content=" http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

Esto genera al compartir la url algo similar a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: eso lo entiendo, pero mi enrollo esta en que si alguien le da click a ese articulo compartido se abra una pagina pero con esa información que se a generado dinamicamete

Comment: Para eso debes permitir recibir los parámetros necesarios para la generacion de esa pagina usando parámetros GET

Comment: Ok voy a investigar mas sobre ese tema gracias